# Account Restriction in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Please am new to PHP and i need open suggestion on how to to deactivate customer account after certain period. E.g
if customer do not perform any operation after they hv created an account in the system, then the system should auto deactivate their account

Comment: You can write a php cron job that will check daily what customers haven't been active. I'm assuming you're storing the customer info into a database? If so, the table should have a created_on date and last_login date. Then compare these two fields and if the difference don't meet your requirements then you deactivate the account.

Comment: You can do one thing. You can have two fields in your DB. One is `creationDate` and another is `updationDate`. Created Date should have created date which will not be updated. And `updatedDate` field should be updated on each activity. And one `cronjob` in your background to check for time period of `non-activity` for deactivation of account.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'll need to engage this via some sort of recurring job, and the typical way to launch that is via [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), a common scheduling system for POSIX type systems (e.g. Linux).

If you have a column that indicates last activity, selecting records that need attention is often done like:

```
SELECT id FROM customers
  WHERE last_active_at < DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
    AND idle_notification IS NULL
```

This tests against some kind of "has already been notified" column. That could also be "is active" or "is not suspended" depending on your requirements.

When you send the notifications, flag them so they're not repeated:

```
UPDATE customers SET idle_notification=1 WHERE id IN (...)
```

And include in that list all the `id` values you flipped previously.